# Data goes behind values on starting points(MPAndroidChart)

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I have used MP android chart and made custom y-axis values by using y-axis renderer. My graph shows point data and line data.

My issue is point data goes behind y-axis value on starting point.

I know one way to achieve this is by using custom renderer. But Is there any easy way to show point data in front of y-axis values.

[image]
[image]